# Plotly bars with x-axis offset for timestamps

Tags: r, timestamp, plotly

I want to plot some timestamps with plotly bars, with 1 bar indicating a whole hour.

My problem is that the ticks are centered in the middle and I would like to **shift them to the left end of the bars**.

When the plot isn't zoomed in, it's not such a problem, but when zooming in, more tick-labels will appear and they would be wrong.

EDIT: I need the option `barmode = 'overlay'` as I also have other traces to plot, which are not included in this example.

The picture below illustrates my current and exptected layout and here's some data to make that plot. (Some option I tried without success are also included in the xaxis configuration but uncommented).

```
library(plotly)
library(lubridate)


df <- data.frame(
  ts = seq(as.POSIXct("2019-03-20 00:00:00"), by = "hour", length.out = 24),
  val = sample(1:100, 24)
)

plot_ly() %>% 
  add_bars(data = df, x = ~ts, y = ~val) %>% 
  layout(dragmode = "select", autosize = TRUE, selectdirection = "h",
                 barmode = 'overlay',
                 bargap = 0.05,
                 xaxis = list(ticks = "outside",
                              type = "date",
                              # tickson="boundaries",
                              # offset=1800,
                              tickmode = "auto",
                              title = ""
                              )) %>% 
  config(scrollZoom = TRUE)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would the following meet your needs?

One of the things that I take advantage of sometimes with `plotly` is that you can show different values in `text` that are independent of your the `x` and `y` values used to plot the data.

In this case, we can create a column with an offset time value, `ts_x` and plot the x values a half hour past the time for each row -- If you have a column for every hour, this effectively left-aligns the bars.

```
library(plotly)

df <- data.frame(
  ts = seq(as.POSIXct("2019-03-20 00:00:00"), by = "hour", length.out = 24),
  val = sample(1:100, 24)
)

## Create a dummy column with x offset values
df$ts_x <- df$ts + 1800

plot_ly() %>% 
  ## Plot based on the dummy column
  add_bars(data = df, x = ~ts_x, y = ~val,
           ## Cover up our tracks by not showing true x value on hoverinfo
           hoverinfo = "text",
           ## Give text that includes the un-altered time values
           text = ~paste0("Time: ",format(ts, format = "%B %d, %Y %H:%M"),
                               "<br>Value: ",val)) %>% 
  layout(dragmode = "select", autosize = TRUE, selectdirection = "h",
         barmode = 'overlay',
         bargap = 0.05,
         xaxis = list(ticks = "outside",
                      type = "date",
                      tickmode = "auto",
                      title = ""
         )) %>% 
  config(scrollZoom = TRUE)
```

[image: Plot output]

Comment: This is indeed not a bad idea. I will have a closer look and test it with the original data. My only reservation is that I have about 6 barplots to overlay and I would need to create an additional column for each one then. But if there's no other option, probably that's the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

By default, bars are centered, I didn't find how to change this.
One alternative is to add a second bar, because when there are 2 bars for each x-axis unity, one bar is at the left of the axis tick, and the second at the right (what you are trying to obtain with one bar).

Why not creating a second invisible bar ? :)

```
df <- data.frame(
  ts    = seq(as.POSIXct("2019-03-20 00:00:00"), by = "hour", length.out = 24),
  val   = sample(1:100, 24),
  val0  = 0 
)

plot_ly(df, type = 'bar') %>%
  add_trace(x = ~ts, y = ~val0) %>% 
  add_trace(x = ~ts, y = ~val) %>%
  layout(
    showlegend = FALSE
  ) %>% 
  config(scrollZoom = TRUE)
```

This will create a legend (as there are 2 kind of bars, ones for val and ones for val0), so I removed it.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot do that, as I need `barmode = 'overlay'` as I have other bars to plot aswell, and the 0-values would just be overlaid and plotted for nothing. But thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are not over engineering? Subtracting 30 minutes gives me a nice graph when zooming in.

I'm not suggest you actually edit the data, even if it's what I'm doing in the code. A small function in the call to add bars could solve it? If you overlay other data it could make a mess but I just wanted to suggest it.

```
library(plotly)
library(lubridate)

df2 <- data.frame(
  ts = seq(as.POSIXct("2019-03-20 00:00:00"), by = "hour", length.out = 24) - minutes(30),
  val = sample(1:100, 24)
)


plot_ly() %>% 
  add_bars(data = df2, x = ~ts, y = ~val) %>% 
  layout(dragmode = "select", autosize = TRUE, selectdirection = "h",
         barmode = 'overlay',
         bargap = 0.05,
         xaxis = list(ticks = "outside",
                      type = "date",
                      # tickson="boundaries",
                      # offset=1800,
                      tickmode = "auto",
                      title = ""
         )) %>% 
  config(scrollZoom = TRUE)
```

Comment: I am getting the timestamps from a database and I want the "correct" timestamps to be shown as hover-popup. So if there's no option to define the label offset, I have to go with @Matt Summersgill's answer so far.